# How to decrease Epoch time length and perform substract operation for get one minute ago time in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a use case, where i need to generate timestamp in Epoch UTC format till seconds 1662371646, and perform Substract operation for generate one minute ago time in same format.

below is my **Jolt Spec** :

```json
[    
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "currenttime": "${now():toNumber()}"
      
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "timeOneMinu": "=Subtract(@(1,currenttime),60)"
    }
  }
]
```

Expected **Output**

```json
{
  "currenttime": "1662372281",
  "timeOneMinu": "1662372221"
}
```

Please suggest, How we can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function called **Subtract** but **intSum**, but prefer using it for an integer with less than ten digits. Split by using **substring** function in order to do this, and then remove extra created attributes such as

```json
[    
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "currenttime": "${now():toNumber()}"
      
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ct1": "=substring(@(1,currenttime),0,4)",
      "ct2_": "=substring(@(1,currenttime),4,13)",
      "ct2": "=intSum(-60,@(1,ct2_))",
      "timeOneMinute": "=concat(@(1,ct1),@(1,ct2))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "ct*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on **apache ni-fi** is :

[image]

Comment: Ok...but by-default, its generating time till milliseconds, how we can reduce the time length till seconds, Sharing the code default generation.
`[

  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "currenttime": "${now():toNumber()}"
      
    }
  }
]`

**O/P :** 
{
 "currenttime": "1662398069684"
}